# Running a subprocess with arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I need to run an app called `./duck` that receives 2 arguments. Once it is running, it requires 1 extra argument. I'm able to run duck and to send the two initial arguments but I'm unable to send the 3rd parameter. This is what I'm using:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

donald = Popen(['./duck', 'hat', 'eyes'])
donald.wait()
```

This runs ok, when duck runs it requests another argument "worm" but I'm lost here. Duck is a program that checks if the food worm is tasty, so if I pass the argument worm, Duck will execute and will take some time to decide whether worm is delicious or not. And so on with different types of food.

Comment: How would you normally pass "worm" to duck if you were not using Python?

Comment: What do you mean by "Once it is running, it requires 1 extra argument."? How is this "argument" sent? You say "when duck runs it requests another argument "worm"". Do you mean that `duck` prints a message to `stdout` and then waits for input from `stdin`?

Comment: BTW what did you import `PIPE` for?

Comment: Does this work in your Terminal... `echo worm | ./duck hat eyes`  ?

Comment: Hello,
yes I imported PIPE, and subprocess

This is what I currently have:

import subprocess, PIPE
donald = Popen(['./duck', 'hat', 'eyes'])
donald.wait()

============= It Runs ======
and it displays:
"give me food": (this is where I need to pass the argument worm)

Comment: If I'm not using Python, I would just run the duck as follows:
./duck hat eyes
=====
duck - "give me food:" (I'd enter worm)

Comment: Could you answer the question I asked you please?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the "third argument" is actually input from stdin. So to "pass" this argument, you need to redirect stdin to whatever stream you want to use for the input. [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) takes arguments for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

donald = Popen(
    ['./duck', 'hat', 'eyes'],
    stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL
)
donald.stdin.write(b"worms\n")
donald.wait()
```

If you don't need any other interaction with the program, you can also use `run`.

```
import subprocess as sp

donald_completed = sp.run(
    ['./duck', 'hat', 'eyes'],
    stdout=DEVNULL,
    text=True, input="worms\n"
)
```

Remove the `stdout` argument if you want to see the program's output.

Comment: I like your answer even if nobody else can be bothered to move their mouse all the way to the *"upvote"* button.